# unterminated string meets end of file in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Getting this error msg when the double quotes are mismatch in the string.
Error : "unterminated string meets end of file in rails "

I want to fix this issue not by rescuing this. need to alter the original string.
Help me on this.

sample content:

"\n{"email":"sample@gmail.com","age":2,"description":"HTML CONTENT: <div style="font-family: Segoe UI; font-size:12px">Hi User</div></div>"}\n"

Answer (score 0):

Your string contains double quotes. Ruby currently has no way to know if that double quote should be part of the string or signify the end of the string. You will need to either

a) Use different delimiters to surround the string that are not contained in the string

or

b) escape the double quotes in the string

For a, many different solutions can be used. Here's a few examples:

```rb
'\n{"email":"sample@gmail.com","age":2,"description":"HTML CONTENT: <div style="font-family: Segoe UI; font-size:12px">Hi User</div></div>"}\n'
```

Do note, that in this case, `\n` is a literal backslash character followed by an n, not a newline.

```rb
<<~MY_TEXT
\n{"email":"sample@gmail.com","age":2,"description":"HTML CONTENT: <div style="font-family: Segoe UI; font-size:12px">Hi User</div></div>"}\n
MY_TEXT
```

```rb
%Q{\n{"email":"sample@gmail.com","age":2,"description":"HTML CONTENT: <div style="font-family: Segoe UI; font-size:12px">Hi User</div></div>"}\n}
```

For b, you'll have to escape every double quote:

```
"\n{\"email\":\"sample@gmail.com\",\"age\":2,\"description\":\"HTML CONTENT: <div style=\"font-family: Segoe UI; font-size:12px\">Hi User</div></div>\"}\n"
```